# Set up a Windows 10 Client for a Linux KDC Realm

Tags: linux, windows, kerberos, hadoop

I set up a KDC Server and created a Realm `EXAMPLE.COM`. Here is my krb5.conf file:

```
[libdefaults]
  renew_lifetime = 7d
  forwardable = true
  default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
  ticket_lifetime = 24h
  dns_lookup_realm = false
  dns_lookup_kdc = false
  default_ccache_name = /tmp/krb5cc_%{uid}
  #default_tgs_enctypes = aes des3-cbc-sha1 rc4 des-cbc-md5
  #default_tkt_enctypes = aes des3-cbc-sha1 rc4 des-cbc-md5

[logging]
  default = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
  admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log
  kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log

[realms]
  EXAMPLE.COM = {
    admin_server = my.linux-server.de
    kdc = my.linux-server.de
  }
```

I also added a user `testuser` with password `abc` via `kadmin.local`:

```
kadmin.local:  addprinc testuser@EXAMPLE.COM
```

I can successfully log in on my Ubuntu VM:

```
[root@ubuntu-vm ~]# kinit testuser
Password for testuser@EXAMPLE.COM:
```

Then `klist` shows:

```
[root@ubuntu-vm ~]# klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: testuser@EXAMPLE.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
01.12.2016 14:58:40  02.12.2016 14:58:40  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
```

and I can open my Kererized Hadoop UI.

========================================================================

Problem makes my Windows client. I set it up by copying the `krb5.conf` file from the KDC machine to the Windows client and renamed it to `kdc5.ini`.

I also set the computer's domain:

```
C:> Ksetup /setdomain EXAMPLE.COM
```

After a restart I tried to connect to my KDC Realm via

```
C:> kinit testuser@EXAMPLE.COM
Password for testuser@EXAMPLE.COM:
<empty row>
```

Everything looked fine so far, but when I call `klist` I get only the following result:

```
Aktuelle Anmelde-ID ist 0:0x7eca34

Zwischengespeicherte Tickets: (0)
```

In English something like `... cached tickets: (0)`

I'm also unable to open my website on the Windows client, so I guess that there's an interoperability issue as I didn't have any problems connection via my Ubuntu client.

My browser (Firefox) should be correctly configured on both machines (Ubuntu & Windows), I set the `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris` property to `http://my.linux-server.de` (since I did this, the Ubuntu client can open the site). Curl also works for Ubuntu, but don't for Windows.

UPDATE: Also tried a second Windows client without any success...

Comment: I assume this is a workgroup machine, have you tried MIT Kerberos client?

Comment: Yes, I also tried the MIT Kerberos Client. I clicked "Get Ticket" and entered Principal name and password. In the list below I can see the principal and the "valid until" entry for the ticket.

Comment: @JacobEvans Do I have to configure more than the krb5.ini (copied from the server) and the "ksetup /setrealm EXMAPLE.COM" command?

Comment: Can you get a network trace, taken from the client, filtered for Kerberos traffic...

Comment: honestly not sure,  still trying to figure this out for a krb5 realm trust between 2012R2 and ipa

Comment: Are you sure you named the `krb5.conf` file as `kdc5.ini` on Windows? I think it should be `krb5.ini`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I got it working! I made the following steps on a Windows 7 (64-bit) machine, should also work on Windows 10:

1. Install the MIT Kerberos from [here](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/dist/index.html). I took the actual Windows Version which is `MIT Kerberos for Windows 4.1` and installed it with default settings.
2. Open the file `C:\ProgramData\MIT\Kerberos\krb5.ini` and insert following settings:

New content of the file:

```
[libdefaults]
  default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM

[realms]
  EXAMPLE.COM = {
    admin_server = your.admin.server.de
    kdc = your.kdc.server.de
  }
```

3. Download and install actual Firefox Browser
4. Type `about:config` in the address bar of the Firefox browser and set the following parameters:

Parameter = Value pairs:

```
network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris = http://your.kdc.server.de

network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris = http://your.kdc.server.de

network.auth.use-sspi = false
```

5. Restart your PC
6. Use the `MIT Kerberos Ticket Manager` to obtain a new ticket for your user:
   [image]
7. You should see your ticket in the manager:
   [image]

   8 . Now you should be able to open the web-page that needs authentication:
   [image]

Comment: More help here: http://computing.help.inf.ed.ac.uk/kerberos-windows They use some other tools for 64-bit Windows machines, but it also should work with MIT Kerberos as explained above. For 32-bit Windows, MIT Kerberos is recommended anyway.

Comment: In another words, you say that replacing default Windows Kerberos implementation by the downloaded MIT implementation fixes the problem, even for Windows 10? And why does Windows 10 ignore the `krb5.ini` file no matter where one places it (at least it seems so on my machine)?